# modifier_add does nothing

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, objects

I have a set of meshes loaded to the scene.

When I execute following script I wrote, the modifiers collection of the obj always stays empty. Where is my error?

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    print(obj)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
    print(bpy.context.scene.objects.active)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='DECIMATE')
    print(len(obj.modifiers))
```

Note that I check if the active object was set, and the first two prints always print exactly the same.
But the print(len(...)) always prints a 0 and in the UI the modifier does not show up.

All solutions for similar problems I found only suggest to set the active object which I did.

Comment: You're using the wrong operator on line 6 (`bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply`). You should be using, as you point out in the title of this question, `bpy.ops.object.modifier_add`.

Comment: I'll be damned... I've read the script may times and always missed that. Thanks, now it works.

Comment: Alternatively use `mod = obj.modifiers.new("Decimod", 'DECIMATE')`  and set modifier props `mod.ratio = 0.8`